# To create enum with Raw Type CGRect

Tags: ios, swift

How do we create an enum with raw type CGRect?? 
Tried ::
enum MyRect : CGRect

which throws an error :: 'MyRect' declares raw type 'CGRect', but does not conform to RawRepresentable and conformance could not be synthesized.

Comment: Why you need enum with CGRect type?

Comment: To set the frame of the view dependending on the rawValues.

Comment: Share a sample code for better understanding.